# How find row count in a 2D array in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

**How to find the number of horizontal rows in a 2D array ?**

I have :

```
   Dim i(,) As Integer = {{2, 5, 6, 7}, {32, 5, 4, 2}}
```

**Find the number of rows in i ?**

For example :

```
 // Here, array i has 2 sets of data i.e. 2 rows
 // set1 = {2,5,6,7} and set2 = {32,5,4,2}
 // So, I want the number of sets i.e 2 in this case !
```

Please help !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method can be used to find out the length of any dimension of the array.

Comment: That will give me the total number of elements in the array, that means in this case : 8 !

That is not what I want !

Comment: @Yugal: No it won't, you're confusing it with the `Length` property. Just try the method out, you'll see.

Comment: I got it..

i.GetLength(0) give the required result. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`GetLength(0)` will give the number of rows present in 2D array

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code should work for you:

```
Dim array(56,67) As Integer 'Example array'
Dim x_axis As Integer = array.GetLength(0)-1 'To find out number of dimensions on the x'
Dim y_axis As Integer = array.GetLength(1)-1 'To find out number of dimensions on the y'
```